# Eclipse in Deployment Descriptor

Tags: java

while i am creating one new dynamic web project that time deployment descriptor not creating automatically in webcontent->WEB-INF->web.xml not creating. i don't understand why its not creating.But when i am creating web dynamic project that time one option is coming that to create deployment descriptor when i am choosing that one then its creating the web.xml file but while i am trying to create new Servlet that time my Servlet is not registering automatically in web.xml, its telling to create manually. Please tell me the problem. I am using windows 7 64 bits operating system where i am using eclipse indigo which is 64 bits.

Comment: Please format your question for better readability.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understood your question. Your question reads as if you used an automatic translation service. Especially with complex topics like programming, these ususally fail big time. Please try to edit the question and put it into simpler sentences.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand correctly, you're wondering why the "New Dynamic Web Project" wizard in Eclipse doesn't create a web.xml file automatically, and why the "New Servlet" wizard doesn't add entries to the web.xml.

My guess is that you chose *version 3.0* as dynamic web module version when creating the dynamic web project, and this means that you're targetting version 3.0 of the servlet specification. In this version, the web.xml file is optional, because most of its content can be replaced by annotations put directly into the Java classes.

So either use annotations, or choose a previous version of the spec, or maintaing the web.xml file by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these details i understand your answer.